# Adding a click event to call a function to children?

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` that contains only an `img`. Each `img` has a unique ID. When clicked, I want to pass this to a function to alter an image.

I have tried:

```
$(".gallery_thumbs").children('img').click(function(){
    alert("go click !="+this.id);
    gotoImage(this.id);
})
```

The alert is to test that I am passing the right content to the `gotoImage` function but I am not getting the click event to bind. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: When are the img elements loaded? Can you present the html code?

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: ive tried...

http://jsfiddle.net/aVZsc/

Comment: the code is inside a function which is inside on ready

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you are binding the event before the DOM is ready, I suggest using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(".gallery_thumbs").on('click', 'img', function(){
    alert("go click !="+this.id);
    gotoImage(this.id);
});
```

It is not necessary to include the function inside `$(document).ready()` because `on` checks  every time you bind an event!

Comment: Nope nothing, think must be something else causing an issue perhaps a basic

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've put your code in `$(function() { ... })` correctly, try this:

```
$(".gallery_thumbs img").click(...);
```

Comment: i inside a $(function(){}) and inside a function again but still no joy

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
$('.gallery_thumbs > img').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: `live()` was deprecated in 1.7 and **removed** in 1.9

Comment: Sorry, getting my functions confused!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also..

```
$(function() {
    $(".gallery_thumbs").find("img").click( function() {
        alert("go click !="+this.id);
        gotoImage(this.id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it by adding a class to all the thumbs in the div then applying the click event via the class, was shorter and easier

```
$(".thumb").click(function(){
    //alert("go click !="+this.id);
   gotoImage(this.id);
})
```